# complex usage of html5 history: how to implement go-back and go-into with aware that one can start at any url?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, browser-history

It is a common scene where we need to build a file manager webpage. To make it simple, let's assume we need these functions: The whole thing is a tree. In any node(folder), there is one goback button to go to the *parent folder*, and there are some buttons in a list to go into the *subfolder*.

So here is the problem. If I let `goback => history.back()` and `gointo => history.push(new_path)`, then: if user A is interested in one subfolder, say /root/F1/FF1, and send the url to user B, user B will directly open /root/F1/FF1. That's bad because B can click the `goback` button, assuming to go to /root/F1, but only to find that he goes to blank page because the history stack is empty.

Thus, I wonder how can I do well in such history-state-management? How to implement go-back and go-into with aware that one can start at any url(say, one sub-folder but not the root)?

I've searched the Internet for a long time but failed. If you find that I cannot make myself understood, please comment so I can make it clearer. Much appreciation to any help!

Comment: Have you tried utilizing fragment identifiers?

Comment: @guest271314 Could you please explain how? Much appreciation!

Comment: Instead of using different path names you can use `id` at element `#root-F1-FF1` as a fragment identifier

Comment: @guest271314 Then if user open this subfolder, he still cannot click go-back button or it will go to blank page... You know, when one opens a new page, the history stack is almost empty